# Is there any copyleft (GPL-like) license with both the Affero and Lesser modifications?

Tags: open-source, licensing, lgpl

Looking for a license that covers public network service, like AGPLv3, but like LGPL isn't infectious.

Basically I wrote some useful helper functions I want to allow to be used in any work, including closed-source software, but I want to require improvements to MY CODE to be released back to me and the general public.

Can you recommend a suitable license?

It should also include some of the other AGPL-permitted restrictions (attribution, indemnity), either in the license text or as permitted variations.

EDIT: I should clarify that this software consists only of header files (it is rather template-heavy).  So the LGPL obligations of users would be attribution and an offer to provide a copy of the (possibly modified) header file(s) used, per section 3.  LGPL section 4 requirements to be enable the user to relink don't appear to apply to header files.

Comment: From [this reddit Q&A](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/1mm151/is_there_an_algpl_license_or_similar/), [EUPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Public_Licence) might be an option.

Comment: I'm afraid the assumption in the reddit post I linked to is wrong. From [this tool](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/collection/eupl/solution/joinup-licensing-assistant/jla-find-and-compare-software-licenses) by the EU, the EUPL indeed covers Saas/network but is not a "Lesser". In fact the tool provides no licence with both "Saas" and "Lesser" filter applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914175753/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330792/why-isnt-there-a-lesser-affero-general-public-license) SO answer:

> Hi Benjamin,
>
> I'm sorry for the late response to this message. Because we are a
> non-profit organization with very
> limited resources, messages to this
> address often get backlogged, and we
> are always working hard to keep up.
>
> While we can certainly understand the need for a Lesser AGPL (you're not
> the first person to ask for this), it
> turns out that it's a very difficult
> thing to write. There is no guarantee
> that simply replacing GPL with AGPL in
> the LGPLv3 would be legally sound and
> so creating a Lesser AGPL would
> require quite a lot of work consulting
> with specialized lawyers.
>
> The "unofficial LAGPL" that you point to looks like a reasonable
> approach (AGPLv3 + extra Section 7
> permission) and it does sound like it
> would meet your requirements, but we
> cannot officially endorse it until we
> have received appropriate legal
> advice.
>
> Unfortunately these things take a lot of time and at this stage, we
> don't know when we'll be able to
> tackle this issue.
>
> Please note that this is not legal advice.
>
> Cheers, Francois

Hence, you can try the "unofficial LAGPL" (AGPLv3 + extra Section 7 permission) but you should understand the potential problems.

Comment: Thanks Vitor.  I'll wait a little while to see if anyone else knows of any vetted license, maybe written by a different group.  But this looks like a good fallback.